# what does compiler do when new an object and assign the address of the created object to its base class pointer

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

**Example 3**:(page 377)

```
class A {virtual void f();};
class B {virtual void f(); virtual void g();};
class C: A, B {void f();};
A* pa = new C;
B* pb = new C;
C* pc = new C;
pa->f();
pb->f();
pc->f();
pc->g()
```

(1) In [Multiple inheritance for C++](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjL7fGi-IXGAhUBcawKHQKfAI4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usenix.org%2Fpublications%2Fcompsystems%2F1989%2Ffall_stroustrup.pdf&ei=jpp4VcvuLIHisQWCvoLwCA&usg=AFQjCNHPqDyiu0Gc700VQ-3h_98GX0A_Ig&sig2=BbfKzrRzgJJsFB74JIGxhA&bvm=bv.95277229,d.b2w), Bjarne wrote: On entry to `C::f`, the `this` pointer must point to the beginning of the `C` object (and not to the `B` part). However, it is not in general known at compile time that the `B` pointed to by `pb` is part of a `C` so the compiler cannot subtract the constant `delta(B)`.

Why does the compiler not know that `B` pointed to by `pb` is part of a `C` at compile time? Based on my understanding, `B` pointed to by `pb` is definitely a part of `C` since we `new C` and `C` inherits from `B`!

What about `B* pb = new B;`? does the compile know `B` pointed to by pb is a standlone object?

Comment: This may be a matter of interpretation.  *"...not in general known"* could mean *"known in this example, but not in the general case of an arbitrary `B* pb`"*

Comment: @DrewDormann, can you give me an example that we does not know at compile time?

Comment: Yes.  `void function( B *pb ) { pb->f(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make a few minor changes to your code:

```
struct A {virtual void f() {}};
struct B {virtual void f() {} virtual void g() {}};

void foo(B* bp)
{
   bp->f();
}
```

In the above call, there is no way of knowing which sub-type of `B` `bp` points to. It could be `C`, `D`, or something else. If you step into the call you would know which sub-type of `B` `bp` points to.

```
struct C : A, B {void f() {}};
struct D : B {void f() {}};

int main()
{
   B* pb1 = new C;
   B* pb2 = new D;

   foo(pb1);
   foo(pb2);
}
```

Comment: So when passing `pb1` or `pb2` to the function `foo`, the compiler only knows, ooh, okay, that's a `B` pointer, nothing else! Am I right?

Comment: Sahu, I have another question, can you help me have look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766982/virtual-method-table-for-multiple-inheritance