# virtual method table for multiple-inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, this, multiple-inheritance, this-pointer

I'm reading this article "[Virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)"

Example in the above article:

```
class B1 {
public:
  void f0() {}
  virtual void f1() {}
  int int_in_b1;
};

class B2 {
public:
  virtual void f2() {}
  int int_in_b2;
};

class D : public B1, public B2 {
public:
  void d() {}
  void f2() {}  // override B2::f2()
  int int_in_d;
};

B2 *b2 = new B2();
D  *d  = new D();
```

In the article, the author introduces that the memory layout of object `d` is like this:

```
          d:
D* d-->      +0: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B1)
             +4: value of int_in_b1
B2* b2-->    +8: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)
             +12: value of int_in_b2
             +16: value of int_in_d

Total size: 20 Bytes.

virtual method table of D (for B1):
  +0: B1::f1()  // B1::f1() is not overridden

virtual method table of D (for B2):
  +0: D::f2()   // B2::f2() is overridden by D::f2()
```

The question is about `d->f2()`. The call to `d->f2()` passes a `B2` pointer as a `this` pointer so we have to do something like:

```
(*(*(d[+8]/*pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)*/)[0]))(d+8) /* Call d->f2() */
```

Why should we pass a `B2` pointer as the `this` pointer not the original `D` pointer??? We are actually calling D::f2(). Based on my understanding, we should pass a `D` pointer as `this` to D::f2() function.

___update____

If passing a `B2` pointer as `this` to D::f2(), What if we want to access the members of `B1` class in D::f2()?? I believe the `B2` pointer (this) is shown like this:

```
          d:
D* d-->      +0: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B1)
             +4: value of int_in_b1
B2* b2-->    +8: pointer to virtual method table of D (for B2)
             +12: value of int_in_b2
             +16: value of int_in_d
```

It already has a certain offset of the beginning address of this contiguous memory layout. For example, we want to access `b1` inside D::f2(), I guess in runtime, it will do something like: `*(this+4)` (`this` points to the same address as b2) which would points `b2` in `B`????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot pass the `D` pointer to a virtual function overriding `B2::f2()`, because all overrides of the same virtual function must accept identical memory layout.

Since `B2::f2()` function expects `B2`'s memory layout of the object being passed to it as its `this` pointer, i.e.

```
b2:
  +0: pointer to virtual method table of B2
  +4: value of int_in_b2
```

the overriding function `D::f2()` must expect the same layout as well. Otherwise, the functions would no longer be interchangeable.

To see why interchangeability matters consider this scenario:

```
class B2 {
public:
  void test() { f2(); }
  virtual void f2() {}
  int int_in_b2;
};
...
B2 b2;
b2.test(); // Scenario 1
D d;
d.test(); // Scenario 2
```

`B2::test()` needs to make a call of `f2()` in both scenarios. It has no additional information to tell it how `this` pointer has to be adjusted when making these calls<sup>*</sup>. That is why the compiler passes the fixed-up pointer, so `test()`'s call of `f2` would work both with `D::f2()` and `B2::f2()`.

<sup>*</sup> Other implementations may very well pass this information; however, multiple inheritance implementation discussed in the article does not do it.

Comment: (1) what do you mean by "interchangeable", can you explain a little bit more detail? (2) If passing a `B2` pointer as `this` to D::f2(), what if we want to access the members of B1 class in D::f2()? For (2), please see the update of the question.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Please verify me. `B2 b2; b2.test()`, it's a `B2` pointer passed as `this` to `B2::test()` definitely since `b2` is a standlone object. For `D d; d.test()`, the compiler passes the fixup pointer which actually points to the sub-object `B2` of `D` as the `this` to `test()` since the actually calling function is `B2::test()`. If the `this` does not point to `B2` inside `D`, it would cause problems when accessing the members of `B2` inside the function `B2::test()`. This is why I think we should pass a fixup pointer as `this`. This example cannot explain the update. Thanks still

Comment: For `D d; d.test()`, I agree we do something like `d.test(B2* b2)` (means `this` points to sub-object `B2` of D). However, inside `B2:test`, `b2->f2()` should execute `D::f2`. Am I right? Now the problem becomes what kind of `this` is passed to `b2->f2()`

Comment: Also consider the common situation of `void foo( const B2& b2) { b2.f2(); }`.  Calling `foo()` with an object of type `D` needs to work, but there's no possibility for `foo()` to be able to pass a `this` pointer of type `D`. So the compiler must compile `D::f2()` assuming that the `this` pointer hidden parameter is to a `B2` type. However, it can assume that the hidden pointer parameter is pointing to the `B2` type that is embedded in a `D` type. So the function still has access to members of `D' (but must adjust the passed in `this` pointer appropriately and automatically).

Comment: @FihopZz "inside `B2:test`, `b2->f2()` should execute `D::f2`" You are absolutely right! That's precisely the reason why `this` pointer passed to `test()` must be that of `B2` inside `D`, because `test()` has no way to adjust the pointer for the call of `D::f2()`. Therefore, it passes its own `this` regardless of how it was called, and it works, because both `B2::f2` and `D::f2` expect an identical layout of what is passed through `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Given your class hierarchy, an object of type `B2` will have the following memory footprint.

```
+------------------------+
| pointer for B2 vtable  |
+------------------------+
| int_in_b2              |
+------------------------+
```

An object of type `D` will have the following memory footprint.

```
+------------------------+
| pointer for B1 vtable  |
+------------------------+
| int_in_b1              |
+------------------------+
| pointer for B2 vtable  |
+------------------------+
| int_in_b2              |
+------------------------+
| int_in_d               |
+------------------------+
```

When you use:

```
D* d  = new D();
d->f2();
```

That call is the same as:

```
B2* b  = new D();
b->f2();
```

`f2()` can be called using a pointer of type `B2` or pointer of type `D`. Given that the runtime must be able to correctly work with a pointer of type `B2`, it has to be able to correctly dispatch the call to `D::f2()` using the appropriate function pointer in `B2`'s vtable. However, when the call is dispatched to `D:f2()` the original pointer of type `B2` must somehow be offset properly so that in `D::f2()`, `this` points to a `D`, not a `B2`.

Here's your example code, altered a little bit to print useful pointer values and member data to help understand the changes to the value of `this` in various functions.

```
#include <iostream>

struct B1 
{
   void f0() {}
   virtual void f1() {}
   int int_in_b1;
};

struct B2 
{
   B2() : int_in_b2(20) {}
   void test_f2()
   {
      std::cout << "In B::test_f2(), B*: " << (void*)this << std::endl;
      this->f2();
   }

   virtual void f2()
   {
      std::cout
         << "In B::f2(), B*: " << (void*)this
         << ", int_in_b2: " << int_in_b2 << std::endl;
   }

   int int_in_b2;
};

struct D : B1, B2 
{
   D() : int_in_d(30) {}
   void d() {}
   void f2()
   {
      // ======================================================
      // If "this" is not adjusted properly to point to the D
      // object, accessing int_in_d will lead to undefined 
      // behavior.
      // ======================================================

      std::cout
         << "In D::f2(), D*: " << (void*)this
         << ", int_in_d: " << int_in_d << std::endl;
   }
   int int_in_d;
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << "sizeof(void*) : " << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof(int)   : " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof(B1)    : " << sizeof(B1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof(B2)    : " << sizeof(B2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof(D)     : " << sizeof(D) << std::endl << std::endl;

   B2 *b2 = new B2();
   D  *d  = new D();
   b2->test_f2();
   d->test_f2();
   return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
sizeof(void*) : 8
sizeof(int)   : 4
sizeof(B1)    : 16
sizeof(B2)    : 16
sizeof(D)     : 32

In B::test_f2(), B*: 0x1f50010
In B::f2(), B*: 0x1f50010, int_in_b2: 20
In B::test_f2(), B*: 0x1f50040
In D::f2(), D*: 0x1f50030, int_in_d: 30
```

When the actual object used to call `test_f2()` is `D`, the value of `this` changes from `0x1f50040` in `test_f2()` to `0x1f50030` in `D::f2()`. That matches with sizeof `B1`, `B2`, and `D`. The offset of `B2` sub-object of a `D` object is `16 (0x10)`. The value of `this` in `B::test_f2()`, a `B*`, is changed by `0x10` before the call is dispatched to `D::f2()`.

I am going to guess that the value of the offset from `D` to `B2` is stored in `B2`'s vtable. Otherwise, there is no way a generic function dispatch mechanism can change the value of `this` properly before dispatching the call to the right virtual function.